# How to handle Linq To Sql inserts/updates that have to go through a web service?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm writing a web application that sits on top of a 3rd party application.  The only supported way we can insert objects in to the 3rd party database is to insert data into a generic "staging table" and then call a web service to have it processed through their business logic.

The problem is this can be pretty slow.

I know in Linq I can provide an Insert* method for each class, that would then handle a single insert.  The problem is that the Insert* method is called individually for each object, meaning that we have the lag of calling the web service several times.  This is an even bigger problem when dealing with associations, as we have to make sure they are inserted in the right order and each one updates the L2SQL object with the primary key after insert.  For a complex object that could mean a half dozen round trips through the web service using this method! :(

Now, the web service itself will actually process multiple things at once.  So ideally I could insert an object along with all of it's associated objects to the staging table, call the web service once, and get all the primary keys back at the end.

Does anyone know a way to make that happen in Linq-to-Sql?

Comment: Can't you write your own `SubmitChangesToRemote()` method that calls `SubmitChanges()` and makes the call to the web service?

Comment: I don't understand how that would help... the problem is SubmitChanges will call each individual insert, and expects each call to actually perform the insert and refresh any data that needs to be.

Comment: I meant that you don't do any signalling to the remote service in `insert`, but instead queue them up and have `SubmitChangesToRemote()` do the signalling for all entries once `SubmitChanges()` returns. Of course, I may be entirely misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Then how would SubmitChanges tie together the associations?  The primary keys wouldn't exist until after SubmitChangesToRemote was called.  I'd basically need to re-implement SubmitChanges...